# Where can I find the source code for pcap dump?

Tags: c, linux, networking, pcap

I need to figure out the inner workings of the function pcap_dump (https://linux.die.net/man/3/pcap_dump) however I cannot seem to find the source code for it anywhere.

Does anyone know where I can find this (and possibly the starting line of the function's code, in case I have just missed it in the correct file)? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Looks like it's from [LIBPCAP](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap) library by "The Tcpdump Group". Sources of `pcap_dump` are [here on Github](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/libpcap/blob/master/sf-pcap.c#L741).

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly what I needed!